# WPF ItemList ItemTemplate Border issue

Tags: wpf, listview, itemtemplate, cornerradius

I have an ItemList with an implemented ItemTemplate that looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid Width="90" Height="100"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now this works perfectly fine as expected.
The problem occurs when i try to add a Border with a curved corner.

```
    <DataTemplate>
       <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15">
          <Grid Width="90" Height="100"/>
       </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This results in a Grid with a sharp/default corners. And BEHIND the Grid i can see the red border with curved corners.

Question: How a Grid within an ItemTemplate have a proper corner radius?

Comment: A couple of things, `ItemList` does not exists as Control in Wpf, looking at the tags i saw that you pick `ListView`, so maybe it's better if you specify that.
That said, each item is contained in a `ListViewItem` that has a default style, that could be the reason for you problem (also because a `Grid` doesn't render anything).

You should have two options: create a new `ListViewItem` style, or fill `ListViewItem.ItemContainerStyle`. Probably the latter is the easier.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: Behind? What sharp borders are you referring to? Please provide a picture or something that clarifies your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `Margin` to the `Grid` so that it fits within the curved corners. My test shows that `Margin="5"` is a good fit for `CornerRadius="15"`.

Of course, if there's something inside the `Grid` that has a solid background, the background will still take the shape of that child element. In which case you'll need to include more of your XAML so we can see what you're doing.